# How to include a long underscore before the \question command?

Tags: formatting, rules, questionnaire

i am working with a simple question but i can't include underline before the `\question`.

### Code

```
documentclass{myclass}

\newcommand{\line}{\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}}
\\[-.35em]
\hline
\end{tabular}
 }

 \begin{questions}
 \question What is the color of your shirt? \line

\end{questions}
```

### Output:

1. What is the color of your shirt? **__**

   but i'm trying to make something like this by:

### Output:

**__** 1.What is the color of your shirt?

How can I create this?

Comment: The answer probably depends greatly on what the `myclass` class is--in particular, on the definition of the `questions` environment.

Comment: That's not a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  In addition to the unknown document class, you're missing the `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`.

Comment: @Kayla: Please post your TeX/LaTeX/etc. related questions here, on the main site! [meta], however, is intended for questions _about_ the main site, e.g. if you don't know how to accept an answer, if your reputation seems odd, or if you would like to discuss the reasons for a question being closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the `questions` environment is that of the [`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) class: Redefine `\questionlabel`.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}\thequestion.}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question\label{q:test} What is the color of your shirt? 
\end{questions}

See question~\ref{q:test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: redefining the command indid make it. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 2):

like spaces, drawn rules (e.g. `\hline`) get ignored at the beginning of a line, so you need to put a "stopper" in front if you want it to be output.  add `\leavevmode` before `\hdline`.